SymPy: sum-product idendities for hyperbolic cosh and sinh functions
I have SymPy expressions as sinh(x) + sinh(y) and I would like to express them as the product
2 sinh((x + y) / 2) cosh((x - y) / 2).
With simplify I can do the reverse and transform the product into the sum and I also know that there is a way to achieve the product to sum transformation on sine and cosine. However, I did not (yet) find a way to achieve what I want with sinh/cosh.
Is there a function or a workaround in SymPy to transform the sum of hyperbolic functions into a product?

If you don't have any regular trig functions to worry about, then you can cast the hyperbolics to regular trig functions, use a targeted Fu transform, and recast to hyperbolics:
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import *
from sympy.simplify.fu import _osborne as toh,_osbornei as fromh
>>> eq = sinh(x) + sinh(y)
>>> toh(TR9(fromh(eq)))
2*sinh(x/2 + y/2)*cosh(x/2 - y/2)

You can read about the Fu transformations here.

Thanks! Your answer solves my issue. I am actually using the Fu simplifications to do the sum -> product trafo for regular sine and cosine. I get from your answer that there is no dedicated function to do it with the hyperbolic cousines and I must fall back to your work-around. I will open an issue on git hub for it because I think that it would be good to have something dedicated for the hyperbolic functions.

When I looked at the doc page I didn't see that there are hidden functions for handling this Osborne transformation. I updated the answer to import and use those helpers.
